# Retrieve document in Firestore and validate against user's entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to successfully retrieve a document in Firebase Firestore in JavaScript. But would like to validate that document against a user's entry in order to auth that individual into the page.

Using console log I see that I have retrieved the record but it is not matching it against the text inputted by the end user.

How is this accomplished?

I am using Vuejs. And want to password protect one page.

In jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oL4bondy/4/

HTML

```
        <div v-if="!isLoggedIn">
      <h2>Please log in first.</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form @submit.prevent="validatePin">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input v-model="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    export default {
  name: "add-post",

  data() {
    return {
      password: "",
      isLoggedIn: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    validatePin() {
      const docRef = db.collection("passwords").doc("user");
      docRef
        .get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
      let password = this.doc.data;
      if (this.userInput === password) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: ok so you need to wait for the data in the `then()` method. Which means set your password const in the 'then' method. However I am telling you how to fix your problem fudementally, so when it comes to best practice you should NOT be comparing passwords in your client though, as this is terrible practice. Please use Firebase Auth for any sort of authentications needs if you are already using Firebase. They set up the databases for authorization rules from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Firebase.auth()` for this. In particular, the `.onAuthStateChanged` method/listener will fire after page load. That's where you want to process user/UI access.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, but mostly it's related to the fact that the document is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. The solution is to move all the code that needs the document **into** the `then()` that is called once the document is loaded. So:

```
validatePin() {
  const docRef = db.collection("passwords").doc("user");
  docRef
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        let password = this.doc.data;
        if (this.userInput === password) {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          // TODO: do whatever needs to happen once the user is logged in
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```